Add 2nd gmail address/alias?
Say someone gets married and hyphenates their name (e.g. Sally Johnson-Jones). They have a gmail account: sallyjohnsonjones@gmail.com
Now, 20 years later, they divorce and their name is again Sally Johnson.
The perfect thing would be to change their gmail address and set up a forward on the old address. However, I read in the Google support docs that this cannot be done (Change the email address for your account).
I think plan B is: sallyjohnsonjones@gmail.com continues, but within that account there is a 2nd email address: sallyjohnson@gmail.com — so email can be sent and received via both addresses, and the 2nd address can be the default "from" address, so things migrate over time.
I can't find a document that spells this out.
Suggestions?
